# chrome, jquery, and hovering on a table row

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, chromium

I believe this might be a problem with my browser. Chromium 17.0.963.56 (Developer Build 121963 Linux) Ubuntu 11.04 As it works with firefox 10.0.2. Hopefully it is not a problem with safari, opera, or IE.  But these are the two browsers that are convenient for my testing.

#### here is a quick fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/B4Eef/

When you hover ( `hoverIntent()` in production) over a table row a `<span>` in the last cell of the row should `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` appropriately. It works, except when moving between cells (border) or each row the `fadeOut()` is triggered while never leaving the `<tr>`

So is this a browser bug or is Chromium taking the proper action? Regaurdless, can anyone ponder a way so that fadeOut is not triggered until it is time?

### HTML

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>    
        <th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>Some Text To Fill Out the Row</td>
        <td> ...<span class="hide">Hidden</span></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>2.</td>
        <td>Some Text To Fill Out the Row</td>
        <td> ...<span class="hide">Hidden</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3.</td>
        <td>Some Text To Fill Out the Row</td>
        <td> ...<span class="hide">Hidden</span></td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>​
```

### CSS

```
.hide {display: none;} 
td { border: 2px solid #333; padding: 1em; background: #eee; } 
td:last-child { width: 4em; }​
th { border: 2px solid #333; padding: 1em; background: #ccc; }
```

### Javascript/Jquery

```
$('tbody').find('tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.hide').fadeIn();
}, function() {
    console.log('fading fast');    
    $(this).find('.hide').fadeOut();
});​
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work properly for me (I'm also using Chrome).

Comment: It is also working in Safari.

Comment: technically, I'm using chromium, not chrome. I'm glad it is working in chrome and safari however. I'm afraid to check IE. Or just don't feel like booting up the VM

Comment: Have the same problem. Was able to reproduce the issue in chrome, but not in opera/firefox/ie.